# Scala case class instantiate when you have not-used-in-equals properties

Tags: scala, case-class

Have an academic class:

```
case class A3(name: String)(val s: String) {}
```

Trying to instantiate it. I tried

1. `val v = A3("la")`
2. `val v = A3("la", "ba")`

Neither worked. Looked at a book, http://techbus.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/scala/9780981531687/case-classes-and-pattern-matching/case_classes_and_pattern_matching_html

I googled but could not get the answer.

Comment: Please don't put "solved" in the title.  If an answer has helped, accept it which lets us know that the problem is solved.  Otherwise, you may post your own answer and accept that a few days later if no answer here helped entirely.

Comment: First, `s` is not an optional property. And second, try to avoid `var` declarations in case classes. That is bad style and leads to confusing code.

Comment: @jmg Not optional. right whats the correct word? params that can have defaults? About var How else to expose to outside world/ i read you do that to make scala make a public getter

Comment: @jmg sorry params that are not used in toString and equals. Forgot why i wanted them :)

Comment: @tgkprog You should be using `val` instead of `var`.  Avoid `var` and just use `val` in Scala.

Comment: right @puhlen mostly use vals. needed a var for this but - your right will make a new Pojo when needed instead. keep going back to 1990 books and memory when its fine nowadays for big data analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala IDE messages did not help (Correction : they do, but the tool tip box was not big enough and had a black background, missed the important part, see below REPL output). REPL helped, need to use two sets of parenthesis like:

```
val v = A3("ga")("mu")
```

Full repl:

> scala> case class A3(name: String)(var s : String) {} defined class A3
>
> scala>   val v3 = A3("a2") :13: error: missing argument list
>   for method apply in object A3 Unapplied methods are only converted to
>   functions when a function type is expected. You can make this
>   conversion explicit by writing `apply _` or `apply(_)(_)` instead of
>   `apply`.
>            val v3 = A3("a2")
>                       ^
>
> scala> val v3 = A3("a2")("s") v3: A3 = A3(a2)

Comment: So you have a constructor (actually the `apply()` method of the companion object) which takes two curried parameters. Try to invoke it with one parameter and it doesn't work. Invoke it with two parameters, in curried format, and it _does_ work.  I'm not seeing any mystery here.